# .htaccess mobile redirect seen by all visitors after first mobile hit

Tags: html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I very recently migrated to a new web host.

I have a redirect in htaccess, that sends mobile users to a mobile site, based on the detected user_agent. This htaccess and associated website/s worked perfectly with my old host.

With my current host, whenever I enable this rewrite rule, as soon as a mobile user visits the root of desktop site, they as expected, get redirected to the mobile site however, all subsequent requests to the desktop site on any device, get redirected to the mobile site. i.e. it appears that the redirect to the mobile is cached and that cached redirect then gets served to all visitors regardless of user_agent until I disable the htaccess and they clear their caches.

My hosting company say that they are not developers and they cannot help with my code, that there is something wrong with it that's causing this issue but they can't tell me what. :-|

Please could someone cast their eyes over the below and tell me what if anything, is wrong with it.

ps. This is shared hosting so i don't have access to the logs.

```sh
RewriteEngine on
# http://mywebsite.co.uk => https://www.mywebsite.co.uk
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]


# https://mywebsite.co.uk => https://www.mywebsite.co.uk
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]


## Redirect to mobile site

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge\ |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera\ m(ob|in)i|palm(\ os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows\ ce|xda|xiino [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a\ wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r\ |s\ )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1\ u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp(\ i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-|\ |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac(\ |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt(\ |\/)|klon|kpt\ |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg(\ g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-|\ |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v\ )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v\ )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-|\ )|webc|whit|wi(g\ |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-) [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mobile\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mobile.mywebsite.co.uk [E=NO_CACHE,R,L]

Header always set Cache-Control "private, no-cache" env=NO_CACHE
```

Adding my entire htaccess here if that helps?

```
# Use HTTP Strict Transport Security to force client to use secure connections only

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" env=HTTPS
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
</FilesMatch>
Header set X-XSS-Protection: "1; mode=block"

Header set Cache-Control "no-store, max-age=0"

</IfModule>

Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
Header always set Referrer-Policy no-referrer
Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding

RewriteEngine on
# http://mywebsite.co.uk => https://www.mywebsite.co.uk
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]


# https://mywebsite.co.uk => https://www.mywebsite.co.uk
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
## Redirect to mobile site
 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge\ |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera\ m(ob|in)i|palm(\ os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows\ ce|xda|xiino [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a\ wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r\ |s\ )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1\ u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp(\ i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-|\ |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac(\ |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt(\ |\/)|klon|kpt\ |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg(\ g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-|\ |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v\ )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v\ )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-|\ )|webc|whit|wi(g\ |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-) [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mobile\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mobile.mywebsite.co.uk [E=NO_CACHE,R,L]

Header always set Cache-Control "private, no-cache" env=NO_CACHE



</IfModule>

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are making redirect decisions based on the user agent, you need to tell caching proxy servers and CDNs that they need to check to see how each user agent redirects rather than returning the same result as the first user.

To do that in .htaccess you can just add the line:

```
Header append Vary User-Agent
```

Comment: Interestingly, adding "Header append Vary User-Agent" to the htaccess doesn't appear to have changed anything and the redirect is still occurring - Header append Vary User-Agent also doesn't seem to be being reported by my browser - can that "Vary User-Agent" line go anywhere in the htaccess file?

Comment: That mean you are still getting the cached version.   You should take the time to understand what is doing the caching.  Do you use a CDN, a reverse proxy, or some type memory cache (like a byte code cache)?

Comment: Hosting company uses their own CDN and something in-house called StackCache. they keep telling me that all caching is off however, that's obviously not true.

Comment: It's been really frustrating. Commenting out the above mobile redirect stops the caching after they clear the cache; they are adamant that the redirect to mobile is the issue but say they don't have any developers in their support team so cannot tell me what's wrong with my htaccess which I why I'm posting here.

Comment: Can you verify that that the `Vary: User-Agent` appears when caching has been flushed?

Comment: Cache flushed and now see: 
vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent

Comment: Not really sure where to go with this now - I'm probably going to give up with this hosting company as they really seem to think that my redirect is causing their systems to cache the redirect.

Comment: Yeah it sounds like they are catching system isn't it being the header so I'm not sure that there's anything on your end that you can actually do.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I re-enabled my redirect a couple of hours after they cleared the cache and a mobile hit got immediately cached again.  Looking for a new host.

Comment: Update - don't know if my demand for refund kicked things however, for the last 48 hours....
  `accept-ranges: bytes
  cache-control: no-store, max-age=0
  expires: Sat, 27 Dec 2021 14:58:58 GMT
  vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
  strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
  x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
  x-content-type-options: nosniff
  x-origin-cache-status: MISS`